# Writing a loop trying different values of degree and train SVM with ply kernel

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, svc

I'm trying to write a loop trying different values of degree while training an SVM with the poly kernel in python using the digits dataset. I'd also like every value of degree to have an accuracy and to plot the graphs with degrees on the x axis and the test accuracy on the y axis.

Here's what I have so far...it's practically nothing but I don't know where to begin. Thanks in advance.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
digits = load_digits()

# Create the features matrix
X = digits.data

# Create the target vector
y = digits.target

# Create training and test sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, 
                                                    y, 
                                                    test_size=0.25, 
                                                    random_state=1)


from sklearn.svm import SVC
    classifierObj1 = SVC(kernel='poly', degree=3)
    classifierObj1.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = classifierObj1.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Have a look at the bottom of this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/support-vector-machine-python-example-d67d9b63f1c8

Comment: Thanks this was very useful. I'm having trouble with the loop part thought. How can one write a loop that tries different values in a poly (or any) kernel?